# What happens if root CA expired in Android

Tags: android, ca, android-security

What happens if one of system CA certificate got expired (GlobalSign Root CA - R2 gonna expire in 2021) in Android?
How I can update to latest root CA in my android phone(user-build that never receives any OTA), if one got expired?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Google Play Services to update the devices Root-CAs and other security relevant issues.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/security/ProviderInstaller

```
try {
    ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(this);
} catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
    GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().showErrorNotification(this, e.getConnectionStatusCode());
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
}
```

The required class should be provided with the GooglePlayServices-Base artifact:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0'
}
```

See [this article](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it applicable for system wide? or just within application?

Comment: @VivekRajendran just within the application. I don't think there is a way of updating the devices Root-CAs without rooting the whole device.